# Why does ArrayList.class.isInstance(ArrayList.class) return false?

Tags: java, reflection

Now i'm playing around with reflection and encounter with not quite clear behavior for me.

```
Class<? extends List> listClass = ArrayList.class.asSubclass(List.class);

System.out.println(listClass.isInstance(ArrayList.class));  //print false
System.out.println(listClass.getSimpleName());// print ArrayList
```

Sorry if my question is stupid and isn't new but i can't understand why

`listClass.isInstance(ArrayList.class)` return **false**, although

`listClass.getSimpleName()` return **ArrayList**

Can someone explain this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ArrayList.class` *is instance of* `Class<ArrayList>` not `ArrayList`. Try with `listClass.isInstance(new ArrayList<>())`

Comment: Oh indeed. So stupid question.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call:

```
listClass.isInstance(ArrayList.class)
```

You are checking if `ArrayList.class` is an instance of `listClass`. But it's not, it's a `Class` itself!

Instead, try:

```
listClass.isAssignableFrom(ArrayList.class);
```

Or, as Psehemo mentioned in a comment, use `new ArrayList<>()` as your parameter.